# Проверка файла csv с переменой в python

Tags: python, юнит-тесты

Привет всем,
Я хочу сделать проверку данных которые находятся в csv и переменой. Я использую для этого unittest. Проверка получается, но есть проблема что если данные не совпадают я не могу знать где проблема, а именно в csv или в переменой. Как можно получить информацию в каком месте есть ошибка?

```
tb_row = [u'120 dev 15.61', u'126 kor 12.96', u'128 itsw 20.58'] 
    for i, x in enumerate(tb_row):
        tb_row[i] = x
    rows = []
    with open('/home/max/Desktop/test.csv', 'rb', ) as csvfile:  
        the_file = csv.reader(csvfile, delimiter=',')
        for row in the_file:
            rows.extend([x.decode('utf8') for x in row])
    q = u' '.join(tb_row).split()
    w = u' '.join(rows).split()
    for index, value in enumerate(q):  # comparing csv with web
        self.assertEqual(w[index], value)
```

Answer (score 0):

Если я вас правильно понял, вы хотите в логику вашей программы заложить проверку входных данных из csv с данными которые у вас уже есть. То есть проверка - это часть логики программы. Если так, то unittest вам тут не нужен. unittest - модуль для создания модульных тестов. Конечно можно попробовать запихнуть его в логику приложения, но на мой взгляд этого делать не стоит.

Если данные не совпадают, и неясно где содержатся правильные данные (то ли в csv, то ли в вашей программе), никто кроме вас не скажет, что правильно а что нет. Поэтому я предлагаю сделать следующим образом

```
for index, value in enumerate(q):  # comparing csv with web
        if w[index] != value:
            raise Exception("data not equal, index: %s, %s != %s" % (index, w[index], value))
```